# How could I get input inside my kernel inside a freestanding environment?

Tags: c

I am making an operating system in assembly and I just integrated c. I want to get input but you can include stdio.h inside a freestanding environment. How would I go about getting user input inside a freestanding environment

Comment: Write a driver of your input device.

Comment: how would I this?

Comment: 1. Select your input device. 2. Find out its specification. 3. Implement your driver.

Comment: implement what driver? I don't have one and I don't know how to make one

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to read your CPU's architecture manual to check for the entry in the IDT corresponding to the keyboard (9th entry if I recall correctly in x86).

And add a pointer to the function handling your keyboard input.
Usually what you want in that function is to store each input in a buffer accessible to other kernel functions. In order to "speak" to the device, you will have to follow a protocol. Usually, for simple examples it is PS/2. You'll find extensive documentation over https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard.

Also, you can check this simple example here: https://github.com/TretornESP/StolenOS/blob/main/keyboard.asm

Basically what install_handler does is to alter the IDT to point the 9th entry to the function keyboardHandler.

keyboardHandler searches for a specific code in the device's memory. If found, uses a keyboard map file to translate ps/2 codes to ASCII characters and stores them in a buffer until the return key is pressed.

This approach is as simple as it gets without polling.